# How do I run a custom lucene codec on elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, elasticsearch-plugin

I would like to run a custom Lucene codec on my ES cluster.

I tried searching for Elasticsearch plugins that allows me to install a custom lucene codec but to no avail. I searched the elasticsearch plugin codebase.

Im considering forking the elasticsearch project and editing the `CodecService` class